# Oracle TDE - opening/closing an encryption wallet

Tags: oracle, transparent-data-encryption, oracle-19c

I have a quick question relating to Oracle TDE. Could somebody please explain why both of the following pairs of commands appear to work when opening/closing an ecryption wallet? Is the wallet password actually needed for this or not? If not, when exactly do we need to use the password? Many thanks.

```
administer key management set keystore close identified by "<wallet password>";
administer key management set keystore open identified by "<wallet password>";

administer key management set keystore close identified by "null";
administer key management set keystore open identified by "null";
```

Comment: Its weird - what is the database version? - For opening/closing an wallet it is required a wallet password.

Comment: 11g  ... I've tested similar cmds on 19c and I could open the wallet using "none".

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it's all down to using Key Vault rather than a local wallet. The password is apparently always null in this case.